# Amplifying AC voltage via DC supply voltage

Tags: amplifier, audio, ac, dc

at the moment I'm trying to amplify an AUX-Signal with a 12V DC supply 
voltage. I tried die setup from Here's [here](http://www.mikrocontroller.net/articles/Operationsverst%C3%A4rker-Grundschaltungen#Betrieb_mit_einfacher_Versorgungsspannung) as u can see in the sketch below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9BR4U.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But all I get is just an annoying noise sounding horrible.

For the amplifier I used both the CA3240EZ and the OPA134PA.
Maybe my grounds are not connected correctly.

It would be awesome, if anyone could help me out.

**EDIT 1:**
According to your hints, I tried now those variations of power supply bypass capacitors

**1st:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFVVmI.png)</sup>

**2nd:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLxZBH.png)</sup>

**EDIT 2:**

The voltage is pretty stable at 12,18V as far as I can measure it with my voltmeter.

I changed now the 22kΩ into a 2,2kΩ resistance, so the gain should be 1.

As i decrease my volume the noise also decreases. And if I have volume = 0, one cannot here anything out of the subwoofer.

I still get this annoying sound. I recorded it with my handy and you can listen to it here: https://soundcloud.com/pixel_95/subwoofer-noise

**EDIT 3:**

I get the via an normal chinch cable going into the receiver of a LG HT44S (**www.amazon(dot)de/LG-HT44S-Heimkinosystem-HDMI-schwarz/dp/B003BYQ74A**). From there i use the subwoofer output with the orange and black cable as you can see here: **i.imgur(dot)com/Aw0hmfr.jpg**
Then this black and white cables go into my breadboard in here:

[image]

Other View of the breadboard here:

[image]

And afterwards the outputs goes to the subwoofer in here:

[image]

I put AUX IN normally to my receiver and set the volume to 0. then inverted, non inverted and output are ALL at 6,1V to ground.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Where are your power supply bypass capacitors? Without them the amplifier will self oscillate with all kinds of weird sounds.

Comment: Were you connecting it directly to a speaker?

Comment: thx for your replies, I tried to use the bypass capaticors, as showed above in the **EDIT**, but the curcuits still don't work :/ could you maybe do a schematic for me?

Comment: yes AUX IN comes dircetly from my mixer and AUX OUT goes directly to my subwoofer

Comment: I guess C1 and C2 are electrolytic caps. Is the polarity correct? (+ of C1 to R3 and + of C2 to opamp)?

Comment: yes, the are orientated in the right way ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer**

You didn't tell us you were trying to drive the loudspeaker directly from an low-power opamp!

[image]

*Figure 1. Extract from the [CA3240 datasheet](http://datasheet.octopart.com/CA3240EZ-Intersil-datasheet-7266949.pdf) showing that the most you can get out of the device is 11 mA (since you need it to both source and sink current).*

The opamp is can supply < 100 mW into a high impedance load. Your speaker shows a 3 Ω load.

You need a power amplifier.

---

**History of debug**

> But all I get is just an annoying noise sounding horrible.

This is not really an adequate technical description of your problem. It could mean anything from a permanent buzz or hum to gross audio distortion when playing music.

Step 1: Short out your input terminal to ground. The output should be silent. If the noise persists then it points to a power problem or faulty connection. Is your 12 V supply adequate and is the voltage stable?

Step 2: Your original amplifier has a gain of \$ \frac {22k}{2k2} = 10 \$ and if your input signal is large you may be driving the amplifier into clipping. Use a source with adjustable volume control. Turn the volume down to zero, connect up and gradually increase the volume. If this solves the problem then reduce the gain of your amplifier.

---

The sound sample you posted shows that "music" is in fact getting through but that it is heavily distorted with a characteristic clipped sound. (i.e., The output is hitting V+ or GND and being squared off.

Step 3: Measure the voltage between non-inverting input and ground. It should be 6 V or so and steady!

Step 4: With the input shorted measure the voltage between the opamp output and ground. It should also be 6 V or so.

> *OP's comment:* The voltage between the output and the ground is 0 if the input is grounded.

This is the cause of the distortion!

Step 5: Assuming the opamp is working, for the output to go low it means the voltage on the inverting input must be higher than the 6 V on the non-inverting input. Something is pulling the signal input high. What is the voltage on the inverting input?

Is it time to add a photo of the setup to your post?

Comment: Thx a lot for your reply. I tried all your suggestions in the **EDIT 2** in my post ...

Comment: OK. Just checking the silly stuff: is the sound undistorted when you bypass your pre-amplifier? See the update.

Comment: voltage between non-inverting input and ground is allways 6,12V and stable

and the voltage between the output and the ground is 0 if the input is grounded

Comment: The last line is the clue. See Step 5.

Comment: i tried to give you a detailed view of my setup

Comment: If my curcuit is compete crap, maybe you could just tell me the simplest way to amplify an audio signal going into my 3ohms subwoofer.

Comment: See my answer. Opamps are for small currents. In audio they are suitable as "pre-amplifiers". You need a power amplifier. Where did you get the idea that this would work with a loudspeaker?

Comment: so i only have to swich my amplifier into a power amplifier and i'm done? If yes, could you maybe recommend my a good one or tell me on what value(s) i have to look at. and the idea came out of my mind ;D

Comment: (1) Decide what your power requirement is. (Ignore that 340 W label on the rear - it's marketing garbage.) (2) Decide what your supply voltage is. (3) Decide what your speaker impedance is. (3 Ω.) (4) Find an amplifier chip or module that will meet these requirements. There are lots on eBay or the car sub-base kits.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to add** power supply bypass capacitors across the power pins of the IC. 
Add a 100nF 25vdc ceramic capacitor across the supply and ground pins of the IC.

Add a 470uF 25vdc electrolytic capacitor across the same pins, but you do not have to be so close to the IC. The (+) lead of the capacitors goes to the 12 volt line, as close to the IC as practical. For better performance with bass the 470uF should be 2,200uF.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, as you can see in the **EDIT** but unfortunately they didn't work :/ could you maybe do a schematic for me, so I cannot understand you wrong? would be so nice!

Comment: I think @Transistor has a more complete answer. When I wrote my answer I did not know you were driving a large speaker. I also did not know you were using breadboard, which can yield poor results in some designs.